# Notification IF a cell is highlighted by 2 conditional formattings

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, notifications

Is there a way to generate an alert or a notification WHEN a cell or some cells are highlighted by 2 or more different conditional formattings?
Making that the upper conditional formating overwrite the lower one...

This notification should come **after selecting** a choice from the data validation dropdown menu in A15, F15, P15 and U15, in order to select another car avoiding a crash with the car before or after...

Attached the 2 cases:

- Case OK : each conditional formating highlghted diffrent cells:

[image: Case OK : each conditional formating highlghted diffrent cells]

- Case NOK : conditional formattings are sharing some cells:

[image: Case NOK : conditional formattings are sharing some cells]

To understand what I mean, here's the example I'm working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1skYbRolzLWyxMe06Ppd5tLobksQ8gD9dHrBP3dwgZwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User.

Answer (score 1):

Add another conditional format rule that combines the existing rules, but turns yellow, and move it to the top of the list of formats. For example, in `F6`:

```
=(regexmatch($F$15, "^Red") + regexmatch($A$15, "^Green") + regexmatch($A$15, "^Red")) > 1
```

Becuase those `true` values convert to an integer `1`, there's a collision if the sum is greater than 1.